# How to do a calculation using a variable

Tags: javascript, math, calculation

I want to do a random calculation generator who give the answer.
My problem is that I can't do the calculation.

```
operating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
if (operating == 1) {operating = "+";} else {operating = "-";};
nb1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
nb2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
document.getElementById("calculs").innerHTML = nb1 + " " + operating + " " + nb2;
answer = nb1 + operating + nb2;
console.log(answer);
```

This line : answer = nb1 + operating + nb2;
Don't work.
document.getElementById("calculs").innerHTML = nb1 + " " + operating + " " + nb2; the result is (example) : 10 + 10

Comment: Can you please show the result of the line `document.getElementById("calculs").innerHTML = nb1 + " " + operating + " " + nb2;`?

Comment: `answer` is a string now, but you can evaluate it, try `console.log(eval(answer))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function for "running" code from a string, which can be a mathematical operation. However also see its dangers on the [same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

So try it:

```
console.log(eval(answer));
```

But rather put the calculation in the `if` instead:

```
operating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
nb1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
nb2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
if (operating == 1) {
  operating = "+";
  answer = nb1 + nb2;
} else {
  operating = "-";
  answer = nb1 - nb2;
};
document.getElementById("calculs").innerHTML = nb1 + " " + operating + " " + nb2;
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the variable `answer` is a string.
In order to get the proper result from that string you should use:

```
answer = nb1 + operating + nb2;
result = eval(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you basically want the output to be 20 (number) and not "10 + 10" (string):

```
const result = operating === 1 ? nb1 + nb2 : nb1 - nb2;
```

Will get you the result.

Also, if you want to present the string "10 + 10", don't use the same `operating` variable because the code will be less readable. So in this case you can do:

```
let operatorSymbol;
let result = 0;
const nb1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
const nb2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
const operating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
if (operating === 1) {
  operatorSymbol = '+';
  result = nb1 + nb2;
} else {
  operatorSymbol = '-';
  result = nb1 - nb2;
}
document.getElementById("calculs").innerHTML = `${nb1} ${operatorSymbol} ${nb2}`;
console.log(result);
```